# SQL to update with Unique Values

Tags: sql, dml

How will you update records with unique values in table by just using a single update statement ?

```
e.g. 

Col1
----
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3 

o/p:

Col1
----
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Comment: What database? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update table_name set col1 = rownum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
   select col1, row_number() over(order by col1) rno 
   from #table_name
)
update cte set col1 = rno
```

Comment: Which DBMS allows to update a common table expression?

Comment: SQL server allows you to perform such things